# nodemailer showing error in browser but not in editor

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, backend, nodemailer

my question is that i know that chrome browser cant execute common js modules but in the node js file it is importing everything as common js and chrome is showing error and if i use ecmascript(e26)module to import nodemailer then it says cant import a module outsde a statement so their are two errors how to solve them or my technique is wrong to insert the nodemailer plz help me with it and thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks in advance
here is my code

```js
import * as nodemailer from "nodemailer"
var a=Math.round(Math.random()*999999);
c=document.getElementById("p");
var b=c;
function otpch(){
    if(document.getElementById("optcheck").value===a){
        document.open();
        document.write("You are successfully Logged In")
    }
}
function otpm(){
    alert(4236)
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'mygmailid@gmail.com',
    to: b,
    subject: 'Your Otp',
    text: 'Your onetime otp is'+a
    
};
alert(4236)
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail.com',
      auth: {
        user:'friendsgmailid@gmail.com',
        pass:'itssecret'
      }
      
    });
alert("hi123");
transport.sendMail(mailOptions,function(err,info){
    if(err) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Error while sending otp please check your gmail id which you filled is correct or not ";
    } if(info){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Otp Sent Successfully";
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="module" src="nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js"></script>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
    <h3>Welcome to our site jain services</h3>
    <h5>Write Your Gmail Address</h5>
    
   <p id="p"><input id="gmailcheck"type="email" placeholder="Write Your Gmail" required></p> 
    <h4>click on the button to sign in</h4>
    <button onclick="otpm()"  type="submit"id="un" style="border: 3px solid black; border-radius: 50px;">Submit</button>
    <h3 id="demo" style="color: red;">.</h3>
    <input id="otpcheck" onclick="otpch()" type="number">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: for common js module it shows require is not defined if i turn that into ecmascript module then shows cant import a module outside a statement and i cant change modemailer modules imports as common js